# How to create user in git using tortiosegit?

Tags: git, version-control, tortoisegit

I try to google but not manage to find the answer.

I would like to ask how to create a list of username / password after creating an empty repository.

I have done some research and probably here are a few clues.

a) Generate public / private key instead and give the key to the git user.
b) Use something like git-credential-wincred or git-credential-winstore.

What option would allow me to manage user/password authentication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git itself does not support authentication. Only the listener (ssh or http) which will then call git does.
`git-credential-xxx` is only on the client side (to avoid entering the password). It is not relevant on the server side.

Adding an [authorization layer](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/concepts.html#auth) like **[gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html)** can help you store *public* ssh keys for the ssh authentication. You should not generate private keys and give them to a user (or the private key would not be private anymore).

Comment: Is there any gui tool for gitolite? Hopefully it can run in Windows 7 / 8 well.

Comment: @JimmyLee No GUI that I know of: everything works by cloning the gitolite-admin repo, updating it and pushing it back (for declaring new repos or new users). But it is perl scripts, so it should work on a Windows server (although the notion of a Windows server for Git repo is a bit foreign to me)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. By the way, I would like to ask can I generate public / private key instead for the user so only the particular pc can commit and push the code? Thank you.

Comment: @JimmyLee the idea is for the user to generate (his/her) public and  *private* ("private" as in "known only to the user") ssh keys, and to communicate to you only the *public* key ("public" as in "can be comunicate to any third party")

Comment: Hmm, I think perhaps very sad to know that authorization layer like gitolite and gitosis cannot run in windows. I can hardly find any tutorial for windows.

Comment: @Jim gitosis is long dead by now. Gitolite is only use on the server side, and a Git server is usually on linux. Even if you are on Windows, you can setup a Git hosting (linux) server with docker containers (and boot2docker)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78061/discussion-between-jimmy-lee-and-vonc).